# Алгоритм вычисление ai

Tags: алгоритм, числовые-последовательности

Числовая последовательность {a<sub>n</sub>} строится следующим образом: a<sub>0</sub> = 1, для  любого  i ≥  0 число a<sub>i+1</sub>,  больше a<sub>i</sub>, равно наименьшему натуральному числу, в десятичном представлении которого нет десятичных цифр a<sub>i</sub>.  По номеру i вывести a<sub>i</sub>.

**Как мне это реализовать и какой примерно будет последовательность?**